# Connect Trello with JIRA

Tags: automation, jira, trello

Trello:
We have a board in Trello, with 15-20 lists and 0-30 cards per list.

- Lists represent our process stages
- Cards are our clients

One of our list is 'Project Due date', where we add all projects with a set due date, and we add that date to each card.

JIRA:
We have a board that has all clients with due dates set.
Each client is a JIRA issue.

**What we would like to do is to connect the due date of the Trello cards to that of JIRA's issues, so that they automatically update.**

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the `JIRA via Unito` Power-up?